# How do I find every combination of elements

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a list of elements:

```
John
Richard
Bill
Bob
Walter
```

And I would like to do something to get every possible combination of them in two columns excluding duplicates. Here is the example:

```
A            B
John         Richard
John         Bill
John         Bob
John         Walter
Richard      Bill
Richard      Bob
Richard      Walter
Bill         Bob
Bill         Walter
Bob          Walter
```

As you can see I excude John-John and also Walter-Bill because there already is a Bill-Walter combination. How do I do that using formulas?

Comment: Hi! I posted my answer. Please let me know if it worked for you! I also made included the functionality to append the data to your sheet.

Comment: @player0 See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252079

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my approach:

```
function myFunction() {
var names = ['John', 'Richard', 'Bill', 'Bob', 'Walter'];
var result = []
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1")                        
names.forEach( (element, index) => {
  names.slice(index+1,names.length).forEach ( (rest) => {                                      
  result.push([element,rest])        
})})
sheet.getRange(2,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result);
}
```

[image: Output]

**Explanation:**

Essentially you iterate through the names list. Starting from each element you only concatenate with the next elements. For example, **John** is the first element in the name list, you concatenate **John** with **Richard**, **Bill**, **Bob** and **Walter**. Then you go to the next element which is **Richard** and you concatenate him with **Bill**, **Bob** and **Walter**.
In this way, you avoid having duplicates like: **John - John** or **John - Richard** and **Richard - John**. The *forEach* method helps you achieve this iterative approach.

> **References:**

[forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: That one works for me. Thank you very much!
The other solutions don't work for some reason, even if I do exactly the same.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @TheMaster you are right! I added more explanation to my answer as well as references.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I do that using formulas?

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(UNIQUE(QUERY(IF(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(A1:A)),  CHAR(9)))>
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(A1:A&CHAR(9),  COUNTA(A1:A))), CHAR(9))), {
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(A1:A)),  CHAR(9))), 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(A1:A&CHAR(9),  COUNTA(A1:A))), CHAR(9)))}, {
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(A1:A&CHAR(9),  COUNTA(A1:A))), CHAR(9))), 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(A1:A)),  CHAR(9)))}), 
 "where Col1<>Col2", 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you briefly explain the code? A little flesh on the bones would help a long way.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If A1:A5 contained the names,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY(
  FLATTEN(
    IF(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A1:A5))<TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A1:A5))),
      A1:A5& "☤" & TRANSPOSE(A1:A5)
      ,)
   ),
  "where Col1 is not null",0),"☤"))
```

- `SEQUENCE(5)<TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(5)` to create a "true" upper triangular(with diagonal 0) 2D matrix

```
0   1   1   1   1
0   0   1   1   1
0   0   0   1   1
0   0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   0
```

- Translate the 2D matrix to CONCATEnated names using `IF`:

```
            John☤Rich   John☤Bill   John☤Bob    John☤Walt
                        Rich☤Bill   Rich☤Bob    Rich☤Walt
                                    Bill☤Bob    Bill☤Walt
                                                Bob☤Walt
```

- `FLATTEN` the matrix, Remove empty spaces using `QUERY` and `SPLIT` the concatenated names back